# In MongoDB, how to use the aggregation framework to have little docs

Tags: mongodb

i'm trying to play with the aggregation framework but i have an issue.
I need to known how many people in my database have purchase something during the last month.

To do that i use this :

```
db.account.aggregate([
{$project : {civility : 1, 'purchase.date' : 1 }},
{$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/02/2013'), $lt: new Date('02/03/2013')} }},
{$unwind: '$purchase'},
{$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/02/2013'), $lt: new Date('02/03/2013')} }},
{$group: {_id: '$_id', total_buy : {$sum : 1}}},
{$match: {total_buy: {$gte: 2}}},
{$group: {_id: null, total_buyer : {$sum : 1}}}
])
```

I have this response

```
{
"result" : [
{
"_id" : null,
"total_buyer" : 4443
 }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

this query work because the range of date I use use is small but if i use the same query with a range of date wich is larger like this :

```
db.account.aggregate([
{$project : {civility : 1, 'purchase.date' : 1 }},
{$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/01/2013'), $lt: new     Date('03/01/2013')} }},
{$unwind: '$purchase'},
{$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/01/2013'), $lt: new    Date('03/01/2013')} }},
{$group: {_id: '$_id', total_buy : {$sum : 1}}},
{$match: {total_buy: {$gte: 2}}},
{$group: {_id: null, total_buyer : {$sum : 1}}}
])
```

i have this :

```
{
"errmsg" : "exception: sharded pipeline failed on shard shard0000: { errmsg: \"exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)\", code: 16389, ok: 0.0 }",
"code" : 16390,
"ok" : 0
}
```

is there something i do wrong or i can't do what i need to do ?

thanks in advance

Comment: prior to the first $group everything is done on the shards in parallel but to group results each shard's result is brought to mongos but it is limited to 16MB - if you can maximize reduction of the document prior to $group - for example, once you match on the date after $unwind you don't need it anymore, nor civility, right?   You could try {$project:{_id:1}} before $group since that's all you are using and see if that gets you under the limit.

Comment: In addition, if that doesn't work because you have huge number of documents in each shard, you can always split aggregation and aggregate by week at a time instead of by month and then add things on the application side.

Comment: i try all of your advice and i keep you post.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe my query is bad because what i want is to have only 1 document with the total of document who match

Comment: when i add the $project like this 
db.account.aggregate([
    {$project : {civility : 1, 'purchase.date' : 1 }},
    {$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/01/2013'), $lt: new Date('03/01/2013')} }},
    {$unwind: '$purchase'},
    {$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/01/2013'), $lt: new Date('03/01/2013')} }},
    {$project:{_id:1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', total_buy : {$sum : 1}}},
    {$match: {total_buy: {$gte: 2}}},
    {$group: {_id: null, total_buyer : {$sum : 1}}}
])
i have the same error. so that's mean i have to do otherwise ?

Comment: Could you please provide example of an item from yours collection.

Comment: it's just an example of purchase subdocument
"purchase": {
     "0": {
       "productId"▼: NumberInt(68),
       "price": NumberInt(209),
       "reference": "or",
       "date": ISODate("2013-02-08T23:00:00.0Z"),
       "validated": NumberInt(0) 
    },
     "1": {
       "productId": NumberInt(60),
       "price": NumberInt(79),
       "reference": "or",
       "date": ISODate("2013-02-26T23:00:00.0Z"),
       "validated": NumberInt(0) 
    },

is that you asking for ?

Comment: looks like you are actually only adding up the buyers who bought more than two things during this time period, is that right?  Two more questions:  how many documents are in your collection (total) and what is your shard key?

Comment: Hi sorry i didn't see your message ...

Comment: Hi sorry i didn't see your message ...
the exemple i post is only the subcollection which contain all of things which ar buy by one people. In my collection I have 2 millions of documents and for each i have between 10 and 100 subdocument for the purchase.
My shardKey is the MD5
here you can find an entire document
http://pastebin.com/uGGutZNk
thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your document shows, that **"purchase" is not an array** but a sub-document: purchase: { "1": { productId .... If this is really so, your query cannot work, as it cannot select on "purchase.date", nor can it $unwind", in fact, you will not be able to use aggregate() - so is it an array or not? If not: can you alter the collection to make arrays of these fields (purchase, media, analytic...)?

Comment: This is an old question, but it might be worth pointing out that by now, using the development version 2.5.2, it's possible to return a cursor from the aggregation pipeline, so there's no longer a limit on the result size, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-operation-may-return-a-cursor

Comment: @ronasta FYI, arrays are represented as embedded documents with position indicated by subdocument keyname i.e. "0", "1", etc. as per bson spec.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are a couple of things you can do to improve your aggregation:

1) add a `$project` to avoid passing through fields which you have already used (everything but the `_id`

2) you say you want number of buyers who bought anything but you are filtering to only keep buyers who bought two or more "times" or "things" during the time period.

Result:

```
db.account.aggregate([
   {$project : {civility : 1, 'purchase.date' : 1 }},
   {$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/01/2013'), $lt: new     Date('03/01/2013')} }},
   {$unwind: '$purchase'},
   {$match: {civility : 1 ,'purchase.date': {$gte: new Date('02/01/2013'), $lt: new Date('03/01/2013')} }},
   {$project: {_id  :1}}, 
   {$group: {_id: '$_id', total_buys : {$sum : 1}}},
   {$group: {_id: null, total_buyers : {$sum : 1}}}
])
```

Given the size of your `_id` field, that should work in current version (2.4) as long as each shard matches no more than about 420,000 documents.  With each document representing a purchase, I suspect you may still run into a limit, so you have several choices:

1) wait till 2.6 (currently available as unstable development release 2.5.2) which eliminates the restriction on size of data set (here it's not the final size, but the size that shard0000 must pass back to mongos that's the issue).
2) use a different method to count distinct buyers during particular time period (if that's what you really want - that's not quite what your original aggregation is counting).